# asp:gridview dynamically created columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview which gets populated with the help of a sqldatasource.

Once the gridview is created I want to add a manual column created Notes so that the user can enter notes for each row and then click the submit the form.

In the `<Columns>` field of the grid view I have this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Notes">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNotes" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

This actually creates the new column just fine but when I enter data in the textboxes it disappears when clicking submit.
In the submit even I iterate through each gridview row like so:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gvResults.Rows)
{ 
   row.Cells[0].Text = 
   ...
   string notes = (row.Cells[10].FindControl("txtNotes") as TextBox).Text;
}
```

So the string notes is always empty, it seems that on postback the value is reset; because it recreates the txtNotes textbox.

How can I keep the value on postback?

Comment: Which page event are you iterating through the the rows?

Comment: And are you binding the grid on postback?

Comment: iterate through this event: `protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you bind the GridView, make sure you check to see if it's a postback.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        LoadData(); //if you did this without checking IsPostBack, you'd rebind the GridView and lose the existing rows
    }

protected void LoadData()
{
    //bind GridView etc
}
```

Comment: sorry the Label should be TextBox, just a typo, it is textbox in the code and yes I was rebinding on postback, just noticed that